# Generating 100 uniform different random variables in R code

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to generate 100 samples of Z, where Z is the summation of 8 independent uniformly distributed random variables in the interval [0;1]

I have the following code so far, but I'm not sure if it's correct. I am not sure if my loop is correct

```
eight<-runif(8,0,1) #Uses the runif function to generate 8 uniform 0-1 random variables
   Z_1<-sum(eight)  #caclulates the sum and stores it in the variable Z_1
   sample <-NA


   for (i in 1:100 ) {  #Function continues the loop for 100 different values 
      eight<-runif(8,0,1); #Creates sum loop for 8 independent values uniform 0-1 random variables.
      Z_1<-sum(eight); # stores in the sum loop in the variable Z
      sample[i] = Z_1;
    }`
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not use `rnorm(1,4)` instead? Isn't the sum of 8 Uniform variates approximately normal and surely has mean of 4 and std deviation of (well, I think it's close to 1). So just `samp <- rnorm(100, 4)`

Comment: Why not: `replicate(100,sum(runif(8)))`

Comment: I guess the sd is only about 0.8:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution, so you should use `rnorm(100, 4, 0.8)`.

Comment: If you want **useful**  normal random samples, do **not** use this summing approach.  There are reasons why built-in generators like `rnorm` use a transform approach, not the least of which is that your sum of 8 uniform variables will never generate 3-sigma events.

Answer (score 3):

I would vectorize the whole thing. There is no real reason to run 100 iterations when you can just generate 800 observations in one run. Then just use `matrix` and `colSums` and you done

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
Z <- colSums(matrix(runif(8 * n), 8, n))
Z
#  [1] 4.774425 4.671171 4.787691 4.804041 3.513257 2.330163 3.300135 3.568657 5.503481 2.861764 4.533283 3.353658
# [13] 4.230073 4.690739 4.364708 3.094156 4.933616 3.942834 3.712522 2.587036 3.731474 4.388749 4.484030 4.315968
# [25] 4.800758 4.252631 2.716972 5.159044 4.146881 3.244546 4.418618 4.350035 5.344182 3.176801 3.903337 2.261935
# [37] 3.646572 4.286075 3.074900 4.210506 3.172513 4.535665 4.245856 4.184848 4.532286 2.899883 4.473629 4.751224
# [49] 3.498038 3.337437 4.238989 3.349812 3.888696 4.748254 3.029479 4.246619 3.330434 3.879168 3.786216 3.839956
# [61] 3.878997 4.546531 2.863010 3.417072 4.266108 3.141875 4.960758 3.989613 4.373042 4.295742 4.459014 5.561066
# [73] 4.401990 4.121301 3.830575 3.412446 3.812347 5.591238 3.801587 4.454336 4.213343 5.222007 4.300991 2.765003
# [85] 3.293251 5.362586 2.954080 3.036312 3.655677 3.373603 5.575184 4.167740 3.904038 3.884440 2.901452 3.079311
# [97] 4.927770 3.930943 4.169907 2.922618
```

Comment: Thanks. I also need to plot the variable Z as a histogram. The expected histogram will be similar to that of a normal distribution curve.

Comment: Run `hist(Z)`, it does looks similar

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also,
How do i output a statement such as "xyz" in the R console without the code being ouput. 

I have the code :
    print("The histogram seems to follow a normal distribution")